# Label background color mix

Tags: vb.net, random, background-color

I have three labels and one button. I want to randomize the background color for label1 and label2, on the condition that not come the same color in label1 and label2, and with the click of a button I want to get label3 background color, which is a mixed color between label1 color and label2 color.
In my code i have colorlist with some colors.
I want to randomize colors that are included in my colorlist only
thanks for your help

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' Create a List
    Dim colorList As New List(Of SolidBrush)

    ' Add colors to it
    'red
    colorList.Add(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 255, 0, 0)))
    'white
    colorList.Add(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 255, 255, 255)))
    'Blue 
    colorList.Add(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 0, 0, 255)))
    'Yellow 
    colorList.Add(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 244, 255, 16)))
    'Green 
    colorList.Add(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 0, 255, 0)))
    'Pink 
    colorList.Add(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 255, 16, 22)))
    'Brown 
    colorList.Add(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 120, 37, 37)))
    Dim rnd = New Random()

    ' Get a random item from the list between 0 and list count
    Dim randomColour = colorList(rnd.Next(0, colorList.Count))
    Dim randomColour1 = colorList(rnd.Next(0, colorList.Count))

    ' Assign the color to the label

    Label1.BackColor = randomColour.Color
    Label1.Text = randomColour.Color.Name.ToString
    Label2.BackColor = randomColour1.Color
    Label3.BackColor = (Color.FromArgb(Label1.BackColor.ToArgb + Label2.BackColor.ToArgb))
End Sub
```

Comment: How about an explanation of the actual problem?  *"This is what I want to do and here's my code"* is not a question.  If the actual question you want answered is "how do I mix colours" then I suggest that that is what you should be researching.  You can't just convert them both to numbers and add them and that should be obvious.

Comment: yes I mean how do I mix my colorList in label3

Comment: FYI, I just searched the web for how to combine `Color` values in .NET and the first two matches were from this very site.  That took me seconds.  I reiterate, you need to make an effort for yourself before posting a question here.

Comment: Since you're using semi-transparent colors, you can let GDI+ determine the result of the blending. You can use `Label3.Paint` event and draw 2 GraphicsPath objects, adding to each a Rectangle, sized as the `Label.ClientRectangle`. Then: `e.Graphics.FillPath([SolidBrushFromColor1], path2) e.Graphics.FillPath([SolidBrushFromColor2], path1)` (declare these object with a `Using` statement or remember to dispose of the GraphicsPaths and the Brushes).

Comment: Of course, until either of the two color are selected, you can use the Label's Parent.BackColor as the fill Color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not create a new Random class every time you click. Just make a class level variable.
Mixing the colors takes each component of the color (R,G, B) and averages the value. Then creates a new color from the averages.
The rest is pretty self explanatory.

You only need a List(Of Color)

```
Private rnd As New Random()

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim colorList As New List(Of Color)
    ' Add colors to it
    'red
    colorList.Add(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0))
    'white
    colorList.Add(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255))
    'Blue 
    colorList.Add(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 255))
    'Yellow 
    colorList.Add(Color.FromArgb(244, 255, 16))
    'Green 
    colorList.Add(Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 0))
    'Pink 
    colorList.Add(Color.FromArgb(255, 16, 22))
    'Brown 
    colorList.Add(Color.FromArgb(120, 37, 37))
    ' Get a random item from the list between 0 and list count
    Dim randomColour = colorList(rnd.Next(0, colorList.Count))
    Dim randomColour1 = colorList(rnd.Next(0, colorList.Count))
    ' Get the name of the color to display in the label
    Dim ColorName1 As String = GetColorName(randomColour.Name)
    Dim ColorName2 As String = GetColorName(randomColour1.Name)
    'Set the text color depending on the back color
    If ColorName1 = "White" OrElse ColorName1 = "Yellow" Then
        Label1.ForeColor = Color.Black
    Else
        Label1.ForeColor = Color.White
    End If
    If ColorName2 = "White" OrElse ColorName2 = "Yellow" Then
        Label2.ForeColor = Color.Black
    Else
        Label2.ForeColor = Color.White
    End If
   'Set the back color and text of the labels.
    Label1.BackColor = randomColour
    Label1.Text = ColorName1
    Label2.BackColor = randomColour1
    Label2.Text = ColorName2
    Label3.BackColor = MixColors(randomColour, randomColour1)
End Sub

Private Function MixColors(Color1 As Color, Color2 As Color) As Color
    Dim r As Byte = CByte((Color1.R * 0.5) + (Color2.R * 0.5))
    Dim g As Byte = CByte((Color1.G * 0.5) + (Color2.G * 0.5))
    Dim b As Byte = CByte((Color1.B * 0.5) + (Color2.B * 0.5))
    Return Color.FromArgb(r, g, b)
End Function

Private Function GetColorName(name As String) As String
    Select Case name
        Case "ffff0000"
            Return "Red"
        Case "ffffffff"
            Return "White"
        Case "ff0000ff"
            Return "Blue"
        Case "fff4ff10"
            Return "Yellow"
        Case "ff00ff00"
            Return "Green"
        Case "ffff1016"
            Return "Pink"
        Case "ff782525"
            Return "Brown"
        Case Else
            Return "No match"
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but how i avoid that does not come the same color in label1 and label2

Comment: Why don't you try a few things and post a new question if you code fails with the exception or problem with your code.